# OwlCarousel2. Как изменить ширину боковых слайдов при center: true

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, owl-carousel

Добрый день. Использую owlcarousel2 с выравниванием слайдов по центру. Нужно увеличить ширину центрального элемента, т.к. в моб.версии боковые слайды занимают слишком много места. Как изменить ширину боковых слайдов (выделил на скрине ниже)?
[Песочница](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zzwyYB).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    margin:10,
    loop:true,
    items:2,
    center:true
})
```

```css
.owl-item {
  height: 230px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.js"></script>


<div class="owl-carousel">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ширина элементов зависит от свойства `items`, которое может принимать вещественное значение.

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    margin:10,
    loop:true,
    items:1.2,
    center:true    
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте stagePadding https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/stagepadding.html

Пример

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    margin:10,
    loop:true,    
    center:true,
    stagePadding: 150,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1,
            stagePadding: 50
        },
        600:{
            items:1,
            stagePadding: 100
        },
        1000:{
            items:1
        }
    }
})
```

```css
.owl-item {
  height: 230px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="owl-carousel">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
</div>
```